# Install multiple Eclipse plugins via update site

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want to create a bundled Eclipse update site for a single install of multiple  plugins using the Eclipse Update Manager.

Our developers use the following common plugins for development, all of which I'd like bundled:

```xml
EGit - Git Team Provider
<url><update label="Eclipse EGit Update Site" url="http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates"/></url>

Maven SCM Plugin
<url><update label="Maven Integration Extras" url="http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/sites/m2e-extras/"/></url>

Maven SCM Handler for Subversive
<url><update label="objectledge.org m2e connectors" url="http://objectledge.github.com/maven-extensions/connectors/updates/"/></url>

Maven Integration for Eclipse
http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/1.0/1.0.200.20111228-1245<url>

Subversive -SVN team Leader
<update url="http://download.eclipse.org/technology/subversive/1.0/update-site/" label="Subversive update site 1.0.x"/>
<discovery url="http://download.eclipse.org/technology/subversive/1.0/update-site/" label="Subversive update site 1.0.x"/></url>


Subversive SVN Connectors
<url><update label="Subversive connectors update site 2.3.x" url="http://community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/3.0/update-site/"/>

SVN Kit 1.3.7
<discovery label="Subversive connectors update site 2.3.x" url="http://community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/3.0/update-site/"/>
   </url>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Alternative 1: [Composite repositories](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/p2_composite_repositories.htm)**

With a composite repository you have basically a "super" update site, pointing to all the other update sites. You only need to take the 2 files from the Eclipse help and add all your update site locations as child location at the bottom.

Drawback: When you go to this update site, you can install all the plugins from all the sites, not only the ones you wanted.

**Alternative 2: [Update site mirroring](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/update%255Fstandalone.html)**

With the deprecated update command line manager application in Eclipse you can mirror single features from remote update sites to a local update site. I've not yet found that ability in the new P2 director application.

Benefit: That way your developers really only get the features you want.
Drawback: You need to do some more scripting.

**Alternative 3: [Manually import the listed features in one step](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/whatsNew/platform_whatsnew.html#Install)** (click "Install/Update" link afterwards)

If you have installed those features on one machine, you can use File -> Export -> Installation -> From existing installation to create a small text file containing those features and their update sites. Your other developers can import those using File -> Import -> Installation -> Install software items from file.

Benefit: No scripting, no update site hosting necessary. You can manage that export file in a version control system easily.
Drawback: Not started from update manager UI (but uses the same underlying P2 techniques).

Comment: Thanks, I have used the third option and it worked. I may explore the other two options later.